# GameCenter match by locale

Tags: ios, localization, game-center

I have a game that relies very heavily on text-based communication, and therefore, I would like to only match players with other players who have the same language settings set, provided it is reasonable (i. e. one of the languages my app is localized for).

Now, when I get the preferred language, it is a string. The matchmaking object's player group, however, is an integer. What would be the best method to use integers for locales? Are they natively indexed in iOS, or do I have to provide my own indices?

Additionally, some people speak several languages. I can get the preferred languages from the system settings, but, as far as I understand, it's simply all the languages with varying order. Is there anyway for me to extract useful information as to which other languages besides the current one would actually be suitable for the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game Center matchmaking is not flexible enough to handle your multi-language scenario.  I'd suggest you make the user select one.

You will need to provide your own indexes for the languages you want to support.